# How to add cors to nginx in elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: nginx, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I spent days now in researching on how to add some headers to nginx. All I try to do is adding these lines:

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

What is the best way to put these lines into the nginx.conf?
Is there also a way to not overwrite the standard nginx.conf just in case beanstalk updates the settings so I wont miss it?

Answer (score 3):

The default elastic beanstalk nginx.conf seems to have this line toward the end :

> include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

(Well, I can tell you that's what the file looks like for the docker solution stack versions 1.4.1 and 2.0.4, no idea if that's guaranteed across all solution stacks).

So I think one way would be to to drop a file named `whatever.conf` into the `/etc/nginx/conf` directory using the [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files) mechanism .